# C++ vector content not changed while using iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector with integer elements {1,2,3,4} and I was trying to remove the last element in my func method. It worked fine when I used pop_back() and back(). But when I used an iterator in the method, it said the last element is still 4.

Also, if I tried to print the last element of the vector back in my main method, it still outputs 4.

Can someone kindly explain to me what I should do if I want to change the content of my vector in a method other than main?

My code:

```
using namespace std;

void func(vector<int> array) {
    array.pop_back();    
    cout << "array.back() = " << array.back() << endl;

    vector <int>::iterator it = array.end();
    cout << "it.end() = " << (*it) << endl;
}

int main(void) {
   vector <int>  ar;
   ar.push_back(1);
   ar.push_back(2);
   ar.push_back(3);
   ar.push_back(4);
   func(ar);

   cout << "In main = " << ar.back() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
array.back() = 3
it.end() = 4
In main = 4
```

Comment: `void func(int j;) { j++; } ... func(5);` Do you think this changes `5` to be `6`? Changing the value of a function's normal parameter has no effect on values in the caller.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing the vector as a value, which means it's copied in the function. If you want to modify it in the function you either need to pass it as a reference (`&`) or a pointer (`*`) so that the data in the original vector gets modified, not the copy.

```
void func(vector<int>& array) // reference

void func(vector<int>* array) // pointer
```

I recommend using a reference here, as you won't need to worry about null pointers or need to change any of your method (with a pointer you would need to change the '`.`'s to '`->`'s).

Comment: Thank you! But I am still confused about why array.pop_back() "worked" at that point and printed out 3 as the last element..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change passing your argument to `func()` to be by reference instead of by value like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void func(vector<int>& array) {
    array.pop_back();    
    cout << "array.back() = " << array.back() << endl;

    vector <int>::iterator it = array.end();
    cout << "it.end() = " << (*it) << endl;
}

int main(void) {
   vector <int>  ar;
   ar.push_back(1);
   ar.push_back(2);
   ar.push_back(3);
   ar.push_back(4);
   func(ar);

   cout << "In main = " << ar.back() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

then the output becomes:

```
array.back() = 3
it.end() = 4
In main = 3
```

Otherwise, you are modifying a copy of the vector that you passed to `func()`, but not the original one.